# User Agent list appropriate for jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, user-agent

I want to implement jQuery Mobile, but only for mobile browsers.

Is there a simple User Agent detection function that takes a User Agent string and returns true/false based on whether the browser should get a normal website or a mobile website?

This would basically be regular expression matching and programming language agnostic.  But I would be using this in Ruby on Rails, PHP, or Cold Fusion on the server-side and in JavaScript on the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be of some help:

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

Also this, http://mobiforge.com/developing/blog/deviceatlas-jquerymobile  which apparently actually detects support for JQM-capable browsers. Unfortunately its not free!